# Multiple SELECT MySQL Left Join with CASE condition

Tags: mysql

I have 03 MySQL tables as follows to maintain allocating, issuing, cutting, returning and requesting funds under different votes.

Table, finance_vote

```
+---------+----------------+
| vote_id |      vote      |
+---------+----------------+
|       1 | 320-3-5-0-1001 |
|       2 | 320-3-5-0-1002 |
|       3 | 320-3-5-0-1003 |
|       4 | 320-3-5-0-1004 |
+---------+----------------+
```

Table, finance_budget

```
+---------+--------+---------------+--------+
| vote_id | amount | budget_status | status |
+---------+--------+---------------+--------+
|       1 |  50000 | allocation    |      1 |
|       2 |  75000 | allocation    |      1 |
|       3 | 100000 | allocation    |      1 |
|       1 | -22000 | issues        |      1 |
|       4 | 800000 | allocation    |      1 |
|       4 | -90000 | issues        |      1 |
|       4 |  43000 | cut           |      1 |
+---------+--------+---------------+--------+
```

Table, finance_request_budget

```
+---------+--------+--------------------+
| vote_id | amount |   budget_status    |
+---------+--------+--------------------+
|       1 |  10000 | request_allocation |
|       2 |  25000 | request_allocation |
|       1 |   8000 | return_allocation  |
|       3 |  24000 | return_allocation  |
|       3 |  60000 | request_allocation |
+---------+--------+--------------------+
```

01) Allocated funds indicated under the field, budget_status in the finance_budget table as "allocation" , issued funds as "issues" and cut funds as "cut".

02) Request funds indicated under the field, budget_status in the finance_request_budget table as "request_allocation" and returned funds as "return_allocation".

03) Then  I need to generate the following out put using following formula.

balance = allocation - issues + cut

I used following query to do that

```
SELECT
    vote,
        SUM(allocation) AS allocation,
        SUM(issues) AS issues,
        SUM(cut) AS cut,
        SUM(balance) AS balance
    FROM (
    SELECT 
    vote, 
    CASE WHEN  finance_budget.budget_status = 'allocation' THEN finance_budget.amount else 0 end AS allocation, 
    CASE WHEN  finance_budget.budget_status ='issues' AND transfer_status='Approved' THEN  finance_budget.amount else 0  end AS issues,
    CASE WHEN  finance_budget.budget_status = 'cut' THEN  finance_budget.amount else 0  end as cut,
    CASE WHEN  finance_budget.status != 0 THEN  finance_budget.amount else 0  end as balance
    from finance_budget
    left join finance_vote on finance_budget.vote_id=finance_vote.vote_id 
    where finance_budget.status=1  
    )tmp
group by vote
```

04) Then I got the following output and it is correct

```
+----------------+------------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
|      Vote      | Allocated Amount | Issued Amount | Cut Amount | Current_Balance |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
| 320-3-5-0-1001 |            50000 |         22000 |          0 |       28000 |
| 320-3-5-0-1002 |            75000 |             0 |          0 |       75000 |
| 320-3-5-0-1003 |           100000 |             0 |          0 |      100000 |
| 320-3-5-0-1004 |           800000 |         90000 |      43000 |      753000 |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
```

05) But I need to add Returned Allocations also to the output under following condition.

balance = allocation - issues + cut + return_allocation

Therefore, I edited the query as follows.

```
SELECT
    vote,
    SUM(allocation) AS allocation,
    SUM(issues) AS issues,
    SUM(cut) AS cut,
    SUM(return_allocation) AS return_allocation,
    SUM(balance) AS balance
    FROM (
    SELECT 
    vote,
    CASE WHEN  finance_budget.budget_status = 'allocation' THEN finance_budget.amount else 0 end AS allocation, 
    CASE WHEN  finance_budget.budget_status ='issues' AND transfer_status='Approved' THEN  finance_budget.amount else 0  end AS issues,
    CASE WHEN  finance_budget.budget_status = 'cut' THEN  finance_budget.amount else 0  end as cut,
    CASE WHEN  finance_request_budget.budget_status ='return_allocation' THEN  finance_request_budget.amount else 0  end AS return_allocation,
    CASE WHEN  finance_budget.status != 0 THEN  finance_budget.amount else 0  end as balance

    from finance_budget
    join finance_vote on finance_budget.vote_id=finance_vote.vote_id
    join finance_request_budget on finance_request_budget.vote_id=finance_budget.vote_id
    where finance_budget.status=1 
    )tmp
group by vote
```

06) After that I got the following output and it was incorrect data set as follows.

```
+----------------+------------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|      Vote      | Allocated Amount | Issued Amount | Cut Amount | Returned Amount | Current_Balance |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 320-3-5-0-1001 |           100000 |         44000 |          0 |           16000 |           72000 |
| 320-3-5-0-1002 |            75000 |             0 |          0 |               0 |           75000 |
| 320-3-5-0-1003 |           200000 |             0 |          0 |           24000 |          224000 |
| 320-3-5-0-1004 |           800000 |         90000 |      43000 |               0 |          753000 |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

07) I can not understand what I am going wrong. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Where is this column `finance_budget.status` in your table structure and what data it holds? Depending on it, it may be your problem.

Comment: @Jorge - finance_budget.status as edited

Comment: Well, there is one thing that I noticed. You are filtering `where finance_budget.status=1` and in your select statement (subquery) you do: `CASE WHEN  finance_budget.status != 0 THEN  finance_budget.amount else 0  end as balance` why you need this case if you are filtering the status as 1 ?

Comment: @Jorge - status as 1 denotes the un-deleted records whereas if any 0s denotes the deleted records

Comment: Ok, I understood, my question is why the case statement! Since it will always return the finance_budget.amount ? Your current query is always returning the finance_budget.amount sum as the current balance, you are no performing any of the calculations you give in your question.

Comment: @Jorge - The relevant calculation as -> balance = allocation - issues + cut + return_allocation is performed in my PHP code which is in the allocation program. It is working correctly.

Comment: Ok Then, if you add in your question what would be the result you expect it will help for sure. So we can assess what it is wrong as you say it is.

Comment: @Jorge - Sure, I added the expected output.